# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined - Node.js + Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have this problem when I try to get the data from the database

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

I made the web using react and node.js + postgresql. Postgres is in our server so I'm not using a localhost. I tried some other post but anything works.

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});

// set port, listen for requests
require("./routes/noticias.routes")(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

controller.js

```
const db = require("../config/db.config");
const noticias = db.noticias;

// Retrieve all noticias from the database.
const getNews = (req, res) => {
  noticias
    .findAll({})
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred.",
      });
    });
};

module.exports = {
  getNews,
};
```

Router

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  const noticias = require("../controllers/noticias.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  router.get("/", noticias.getNews);

  app.use("/noticias", router);
};
```

Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: add `console.log(datab);` before `const noticias = datab.noticias;`. What do you see?

Comment: `datab.noticias` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about about knex. As far as I know from docs there is a `select` function not `findAll` in knex.

Docs: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-select

Please try following method and see what happens

```
// below line is not required;
// const noticias = datab.noticias;

// Retrieve all noticias from the database.
const getNews = (req, res) => {
  datab
    .select("column_name_1", "column_name_2", "...")
    .from("noticias")
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred.",
      });
    });
};
```

PS: the findAll function is available in `sequelize` not `knex`.

Answer (score -1):

Use db.select('*').from('users') to findAll